# Using Carto API in HTML

Tags: carto, html, carto-js

I am trying to use CARTO API with my HTML to display a map, code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/themes/css/cartodb.css" />
    <script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://cartodb-libs.global.ssl.fastly.net/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb.js"></script>
    <script>
     $( document ).ready(function() {
          //Create the leaflet map
          var map = L.map('map', {
              zoomControl: true,
              center: [43.713,-79.371],
              zoom: 12
          });
    var basemap = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright"OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com//attributions">CartoDB</a>'}).addTo(map);

    var tickets = cartodb.createLayer(map, {
        user_name: 'mmckeever92',
        type: 'cartodb',
        sublayers: [
        {
            sql: 'SELECT * FROM tickets_time_2',
            cartocss: '#tickets_time_2{marker-fill-opacity: 0.9; marker-line-color: #FFF; marker-line-width: 1.5; marker-width: 10; marker-fill: #3B007F; }'
        }
        ]
    });

    $.when(tickets).done(function(ltickets){
        ltickets.addTo(map);
    });
})
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I cannot get my map to display though, does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, [as explained in CARTO documentation](https://carto.com/learn/guides/intro/migrating-from-carto-editor-to-carto-builder#temporary-limitations), BUILDER vizjsons are not compatible with the current CARTO.js version. Until the new library is released, you need to use `createLayer` method instead of `createVis`. [Here](http://bit.ly/createLayer-sample) you have a working example.

**UPDATE**: you are loading twice CARTO.js v3.15 library, and you do not need to load jQuery because CARTO.js contains jQuery. Removing lines 6 and 7 should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have made some changes to my question. I have a base map now in the Toronto area, but I cant seem to map my points that I would like to have over my map. Could I be some how linking my data incorrectly or something?

Comment: I have edited my answer fixing your new code.

Comment: THANK YOU!! That did the trick. Still new at this html! Cheers!

Comment: @ramiroaznar Do we have an ETA on the new CARTO.js version?

Comment: It is still WIP.